# How to filter list with another string list?

Tags: android, list, kotlin, collections

Hello I would like to filter list with data only with type which is in anoter arrays.

```
        myList.filter { itemList->
            typesArray.forEach { itemList.type == it }
            withStatus.forEach { itemList.state.key  == it}
        }
```

error:

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
Boolean
Found:
Unit
```

How to achieve this properly? I have tried also like this:

```
           myList.any { it ->
           typesArray.contains(it.type)
           withStatus.toTypedArray().contains(it.state.key)
        }
```

Comment: read the docs of what those functions actually do. In the first one, you are using `forEach` wrong, since you expect it to have some return value. In the second one you are using `any` wrong, because that is not how you `filter`. You are also using it wrong because you are expecting that having 2 Booleans on 2 different lines to do something, search for the `&` named `and operator` in the docs. One could just give you an answer, but you really need to read the docs and learn what functions do if you want to learn a language. Try from here: [Kotlin Docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/home.html)

Answer (score 0):

To make things simple:
`filter` should contain a logical expression, result of which is `Boolean`, more simple - some condition.

`myList.filter { /* some condition */ }`

Since `Boolean` result of expression is required, you get the error. That is because the result type of `forEach` returns `Unit`, more simple - empty/void value. You can execute a lot of different logic in `forEach`, however the result of the block itself will be `Unit`.

I think something like this will work.

```
myList.filter { item -> 
    typesArray.contains(item.type) && withStatus.contains(item.state.key) 
}
```

Note that filter will execute the expression for every item in `myList` collection.

Answer (score 0):

Part of what you are asking is technically not possible. You cannot have a `typesArray`, because types are not variables and therefore cannot be stored in an array.

Regarding the filtering by type, you could  do it like:

```
        myList.filter { itemList ->
            (itemList is String) || (itemList is Int)
        }
```

And regarding the second comparison, you could do it like:

```
        myList.filter { itemList ->
            typesArray.contains(itemList.state.key)
        }
```

And finally you can combine both at the same time using `&&` or `||`:

```
        myList.filter { itemList ->
            ( itemList is String || itemList is Int )
            &&
            typesArray.contains(itemList.state.key)
        }
```

Comment: types can be stored in array actually... And actually, due to inheritance, there can be filtering by type. imagine if there is `List<Any>`

Comment: @Stearix You're right regarding the inheritance case, I corrected my answer. Thanks

Comment: The OP's just talking about some property called `type` anyway, it could be anything